# Vim: toggle list in insert mode

Tags: vim, autocmd

I'm trying to toggle the `list` setting when I enter Insert mode because I find trailing characters appearing & disappearing as I type distracting.  These settings don't seem to work (list is still enabled when I enter insert mode):

```
set list
if has("autocmd")
  augroup cursorline
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * if !&wrap | setl cursorline
    autocmd InsertEnter * setl nolist
    autocmd InsertLeave * setl nocursorline
    autocmd InsertLeave * setl list
  augroup END
endif
```

Oddly, the cursorline settings seem to work but the list ones do not.

### EDIT

Upon further investigation, the issue is with files where `wrap` is enabled, which means something about my if statement in the cursorline check is wrong, and is causing the next auto command not to be activated.  Why might this be?

Comment: For clarity's sake you may want to move your list/nolist autocmds to their own augroup.  They really have nothing to do with cursorline.

Comment: you're right that group got bloated I should reorganize.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was missing an `endif`, so the condition carried forward to the following autocmd.  The following change fixed the problem:

`autocmd InsertEnter * if !&wrap | setl cursorline | endif`